# Proving $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in X

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two sets and $\left(Y,\mathcal{A}\right)$ a measurable space and let
$f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function. Prove that 
$\mathcal{M} = \{E \subset X : E = f^{-1} (A), A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$.

Here's what I know the function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ induces the mapping $f^{-1}:P(Y)\rightarrow P(X)$ defined as $f^{-1}(E) = \{x \in X:f(X) \in E\}$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ $\implies$ $\{f^{-1}(E)|E \in \mathcal{A}\}$

This is where I'm lost. Any help is always appreciated.

Comment: What properties do you need to check?

Comment: So to show $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$, you must show
$\,$
$(a)$ $\emptyset \in \mathcal{M}$
$\,$
$(b)$ If $Y \in \mathcal{M}$, then $Y^{c} \in \mathcal{M}$
$\,$
$(c)$ If $Y_1,Y_2,\cdots$ is a countable collection of sets in $\mathcal{M}$ then their union $\cup _{i=1}^{\infty} Y_i \in \mathcal{M}$

Answer (score 2):

So we are trying to prove that if you have a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, then if you look at the set of all preimages of subsets of $Y$ that are in $\mathcal{A}$, this set is actually a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$.

So, we need to show three things:

1. $X$ is in $\{ f^{-1}(E) \mid E \in \mathcal{A} \}$
2. If $A$ is in $\{ f^{-1}(E) \mid E \in \mathcal{A} \}$, then so is $X - A = A^{c}$.
3. If $A_{n}$ (for $n = 1,2,3,\dots$) are in $\{ f^{-1}(E) \mid E \in \mathcal{A} \}$, then so is $\bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_{n}$.

So, essentially, for $1$, you have to prove $X$ can be written as $f^{-1}(E)$ for some $E \in \mathcal{A}$.  Do you have any ideas which $E$ you should pick?

Then, for $2$, you have to prove if $A \subseteq X$ can be written as $f^{-1}(E)$ for some $E \in \mathcal{A}$, then so can $A^{c}$.  **Hint:** $f^{-1}(E^{c}) = (f^{-1}(E))^{c}$ -- this is an equality you should prove.  Once you prove it, why is this enough to prove $2$?

Then for $3$, you have to prove if $A_{n} \subseteq X$ can be written as $f^{-1}(E_{n})$ for some $E_{n} \in \mathcal{A}$, then we can find $E \in \mathcal{M}$ so that $\bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_{n} = f^{-1}(E)$.  **Hint:** $f^{-1}(\bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} E_{n}) = \bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} f^{-1}(E_{n})$.  You have to prove this equality, and then once you do, you are done.  But why?  Why is proving this equality enough to show $3$?

Comment: I don't think the assumption is that $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. That's what needs to be proved.

Comment: @JacobCheverie Also, I rejected your edit.  I had previously written "Do you have any ideas **what** $E$ you should pick?" but I changed "what" to "which" because I think it's more grammatically correct with "which".

Comment: All I changed was formatting of one of your $\mathcal{M}$'s.

The question states "Prove that $\mathcal{M} = \{E \subset X : E = f^{-1} (A), A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$."

Comment: @JacobCheverie That's weird.  The edit only showed me for some reason that you changed the word "which" to "what". Must have been a glitch.